# How to hide the arrow in Omnet++ 5.6.1?

Tags: c++, omnet++

How to hide the arrow in Omnet++ v5.6.1 ?
I'm newbie, I'm using connectTo() method to create arrows.

```
gate->connectTo(gatein);
```

How to hide it ?
Thank you. This is my simulation's image:
[my simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDAUI.png)

Comment: Welcome at SO! Do you want to hide the whole connection or just the arrows between a connection?

Comment: Yes, i want to hide all connection. Can you help me :D ?

Answer (score 0):

A connection may be hidden by setting its width to zero. The following code may be used to do it:

```
cDisplayString & disp = gate->getDisplayString();
disp.setTagArg("ls", 1, "0"); // 1 indicates argument of the Tag, 0 - width
```

Reference: [Display String Tags](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:display-strings:module-and-connection-display-strings).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it don't work for me. This is my code to create conection:

```
if (id != this->myId)
                {
                    cGate *g;
                    cGate *g0;
                    int items;
                    int dist = distanceCal(x, y,this->xpos,this->ypos);
                    if (dist <= trRange)
                    {
                        items = this->gateSize("out");
                        ritems = mod->gateSize("in");
                        this->setGateSize("out",items+1);
                        mod->setGateSize("in",ritems+1);
                        g0 = this->gate("out",items);
                        g = mod->gate("in",ritems);
                        g0->connectTo(g);
                        //cDisplayString & disp = g0->getDisplayString();
                        //disp.setTagArg("ls",1,long (0));

                    }
                }
```

This is my ned file:

```
// Base Station
simple BaseStation
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=device/antennatower_l");
        int id;
        int randInit;
        int numNodes;
        int xpos;
        int ypos;
    gates:
        input in[];
        output out[];
}
// Sensor node
simple SensorNode
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=misc/node");
        int id;
        int energy;
        int xpos;
        int ypos;

    gates:
        input in[];
        output out[];
}

// ARPEES network
network WSN
{
    parameters:
        //numeric  energy;
        int energy;
        //numNodes: numeric,
        int numNodes;
        //trRange: numeric,
        int trRange;
        //trRangeD0: numeric,
        int protocol;
        //protocol: numeric,
        //showHideRange: numeric,
        int showHideRange;
        int ssRange;
        int kRequire;

        int rounds;

        int frames;

        int sRand;
        int xMax;
        int yMax;
        @display("p=0,0;b=$xMax,$yMax,rect;o=white");
    submodules:
        bs: BaseStation {
            parameters:
                id = 1;
                randInit = sRand;
                xpos = int (xMax/2);
                ypos = yMax+40;
                numNodes = numNodes;
        }
        node[numNodes]: SensorNode {
            parameters:
                energy = energy;
                id = index+2;
                xpos = intuniform(10,xMax-10);
                ypos = intuniform(10,yMax-10);

        }
    connections allowunconnected:


    //{display("p=0,0;b=$xMax,$yMax,rect;o=white");} //DarkSeaGreen

}
}
```

What i need to do now ?

Comment: Could you explain _don't work for me_ : it does not compile, or there is a runtime error, or there is no effect, etc.?

Comment: I have edited my answer by adding quotes to width value.

Comment: Thank you for your help.